# getimagesize() error in php

Tags: php, getimagesize

So I am using the getimagesize function to get the size of the image. The line I use is the following:

```
list($width, $height) = getimagesize($imagen);
```

The variable $imagen is the right one as if I echo it, I get the image url, and the image does exist.
any idea?Edit: allow_url_fopen  is on and the error I get is the following:

```
Warning: getimagesize(): Couldn't resolve host name in /home/u969736199/public_html/web/productos.php on line 43 Warning: getimagesize(http://snapi2.vv.si/web/images/productos/R2203054.jpg): failed to open stream: operation failed in /home/u969736199/public_html/web/productos.php on line 43 http://snapi2.vv.si/web/images/productos/R2203054.jpg
```

What I get from var_export($imagen); and var_export(is_readable($imagen)); is:
http://snapi2.vv.si/web/images/productos/EE523152.jpg'http://snapi2.vv.si/web/images/productos/EE523152.jpg'false

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: What's the *precise* output of `var_export($imagen);var_export(is_readable($imagen));`?

Comment: The url isn't accessible so PHP can't load the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are retrieving a remote image you need to make sure that you enable

```
allow_url_fopen
```

in php.ini.

Answer (score 0):

The url you are accessing doesn't resolve. If you go to http://snapi2.vv.si/web/images/productos/EE523152.jpg in the browser you will get a server not found page.